# Should the question regarding PHP on Tor be closed because it is off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

The main site has a question with the title "[can php be used on Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/13147/88)". In my opinion this question is not about Tor itself, but more about a misconfiguration of PHP or the webserver. So I would tend to close it as off-topic. What do you think? Is it on-topic here or should it be closed?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think it's a fair question, and both the comments and the user's own answer clarify that:

1. Tor can be used with PHP
2. Future users should check their config when having trouble using PHP to connect over Tor

If this were actually a question about how to configure VHOST settings on NGINX, then it would be clearly off topic. But it's a pretty straight-forward question about whether Tor can be used with PHP, which it can be.